# How to add details to a table created as the result of a many2many field using create function in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

I have a custom model *csm* in my application. I have a *many2many* field as *product_multi* reffering to *product.product* . This many2many field resulted in the creation of another table named **csm_product_product_rel**. Now i need to create records in this table from account.invoice model  using environment and create function.

What i tried is..

```
self.env['csm_product_product_rel'].create({

            'customer_service_management_id': ticket_id,
            'product_product_id': 1,

        })
```

But it is giving error like value error "csm_product_product_rel" while evaluavting. The same code if i use like this `self.env['csm'].create({})`, it is not giving any error. What may be the problem. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the model `csm_product_product_rel` doesn't exists. Exists the table in the database but not the model in python code.

You have defined a relation from `csm` model to `product.product` model. If you want to add a new relation record you need to do this
by the `csm` model, like this:

```
self.write({'many2manyfield': [(4, product.id)]})
```

Where `self` is the record of the `csm` model.

[Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/models.py#L3723) you have a list for the `special commands` to manage the records of the *2many fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you have to write the create function. Look at the sample code below and try

```
def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
            partner_id=values.get('partner_id')
            if partner_id:
                emp_ids=values.get('employee_ids')
                if emp_ids:
                    for line in emp_ids:
                        self.pool.get('res.partner').write(cr, uid, partner_id, {'employee_ids': [(4, line[2])]}, context=context)
            return super(sale_order, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

Comment: I know how to write create function. I need to write create function for tables that are created as a result of many2many field